# Implementing custom layer in Keras (RStudio Interface)

Tags: r, tensorflow, keras

I'm having some trouble implementing a custom layer in a word embedding model using R's interface to Keras. Below a toy version of my code that will reproduce the error:

```
rm(list = ls())
library(keras)
library(tensorflow)

# ================================
# inputs
# ================================

input_target <- layer_input(shape = 1)
input_context <- layer_input(shape = 1)

# embedding matrix for mean vectors
embedding_mu <- layer_embedding(
  input_dim = 1000, 
  output_dim = 50, 
  embeddings_initializer = initializer_random_uniform(),
  input_length = 1, 
  name = "embedding_mu"
)

# embedding matrix for sigma vectors
embedding_sigma <- layer_embedding(
  input_dim = 1000, 
  output_dim = 50, 
  embeddings_initializer = initializer_random_uniform(),
  input_length = 1, 
  name = "embedding_sigma"
)

# select target mu from the mu embedding matrix
target_vector_mu <- input_target %>%
  embedding_mu() %>% 
  layer_flatten()

# select context mu from the mu embedding matrix
context_vector_mu <- input_context %>%
  embedding_mu() %>%
  layer_flatten()

# select target sigma from the sigma embedding matrix
target_vector_sigma <- input_target %>%
  embedding_sigma() %>% 
  layer_flatten()

# select context sigma from the sigma embedding matrix
context_vector_sigma <- input_context %>%
  embedding_sigma() %>%
  layer_flatten()

# ================================
# custom layer
# ================================
KLenergy <- function(args){ # args <- list(mu_w, mu_c, sigma_w, sigma_c)
  comp1 <- tf$reduce_sum(tf$div(args[[4]], args[[3]]), axis = integer(1))
  comp2 <- tf$reduce_sum(tf$div(tf$square(tf$subtract(args[[1]], args[[2]])), args[[3]]), axis = integer(1))
  comp3 <- tf$subtract(tf$log(tf$reduce_prod(args[[4]], axis = integer(1))), tf$log(tf$reduce_prod(args[[3]], axis = integer(1))))
  energy <- 0.5*(comp1 + comp2 - comp3)
  return(energy)
}

kl_energy <- layer_lambda(list(target_vector_mu, 
                                 context_vector_mu, 
                                 target_vector_sigma, 
                                 context_vector_sigma),
                            KLenergy)


output <- layer_dense(kl_energy, units = 1, activation = "relu")

# ================================
# model compile
# ================================
model <- keras_model(list(input_target, input_context), output)
model %>% compile(
  loss = "binary_crossentropy", 
  optimizer = "Adagrad")

summary(model)
```

The following error appears after executing the "output" layer:

```
Error in py_call_impl(callable, dots$args, dots$keywords) : 
ValueError: Input 0 is incompatible with layer dense_2: expected min_ndim=2, found ndim=1

Detailed traceback: 
  File "/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 414, in __call__
self.assert_input_compatibility(inputs)
  File "/anaconda3/envs/r-tensorflow/lib/python3.6/site-packages/keras/engine/base_layer.py", line 327, in assert_input_compatibility
str(K.ndim(x)))
```

I expect the kl_energy layer to have shape (None, 1) but instead I get (None,).

```
kl_energy
Tensor("lambda_5/Mul:0", shape=(?,), dtype=float32)
```

Am I missing an argument in defining the custom layer? I tried setting "keepdims = TRUE":

```
KLenergy <- function(args){ # args <- list(mu_w, mu_c, sigma_w, sigma_c)
  comp1 <- tf$reduce_sum(tf$div(args[[4]], args[[3]]), axis = as.integer(1), keepdims = TRUE)
  comp2 <- tf$reduce_sum(tf$div(tf$square(tf$subtract(args[[1]], args[[2]])), args[[3]]), axis = as.integer(1), keepdims = TRUE)
  comp3 <- tf$subtract(tf$log(tf$reduce_prod(args[[4]], axis = as.integer(1), keepdims = TRUE)), tf$log(tf$reduce_prod(args[[3]], axis = as.integer(1), keepdims = TRUE)))
  energy <- 0.5*(comp1 + comp2 - comp3)
  return(energy)
}
```

But this gives me a kl_energy layer with shape (1, None) which is not what I want. Ultimately the output of this layer should be the same shape as in the original word2vec model (which uses layer_dot - [see here](https://blogs.rstudio.com/tensorflow/posts/2017-12-22-word-embeddings-with-keras/)) but using this custom layer:

```
kl_energy
Tensor("lambda_7/Mul:0", shape=(1, ?), dtype=float32)
```

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

WORKING CODE (credits to Daniel below):

```
# ================================
# inputs
# ================================

input_target <- layer_input(shape = 1)
input_context <- layer_input(shape = 1)

# embedding matrix for mean vectors
embedding_mu <- layer_embedding(
  input_dim = 1000, 
  output_dim = 50, 
  embeddings_initializer = initializer_random_uniform(),
  input_length = 1, 
  name = "embedding_mu"
)

# embedding matrix for sigma vectors
embedding_sigma <- layer_embedding(
  input_dim = 1000, 
  output_dim = 50, 
  embeddings_initializer = initializer_random_uniform(),
  input_length = 1, 
  name = "embedding_sigma"
)

# select target mu from the mu embedding matrix
target_vector_mu <- input_target %>%
  embedding_mu() %>% 
  layer_flatten()

# select context mu from the mu embedding matrix
context_vector_mu <- input_context %>%
  embedding_mu() %>%
  layer_flatten()

# select target sigma from the sigma embedding matrix
target_vector_sigma <- input_target %>%
  embedding_sigma() %>% 
  layer_flatten()

# select context sigma from the sigma embedding matrix
context_vector_sigma <- input_context %>%
  embedding_sigma() %>%
  layer_flatten()

# ================================
# custom layer
# ================================
KLenergy <- function(args){ # args <- list(mu_w, mu_c, sigma_w, sigma_c)
  comp1 <- tf$reduce_sum(tf$div(args[[4]], args[[3]]), axis = as.integer(1), keepdims = TRUE)
  comp2 <- tf$reduce_sum(tf$div(tf$square(tf$subtract(args[[1]], args[[2]])), args[[3]]), axis = as.integer(1), keepdims = TRUE)
  comp3 <- tf$subtract(tf$log(tf$reduce_prod(args[[4]], axis = as.integer(1), keepdims = TRUE)), tf$log(tf$reduce_prod(args[[3]], axis = as.integer(1), keepdims = TRUE)))
  energy <- 0.5*(comp1 + comp2 - comp3)
  return(energy)
}

kl_energy <- layer_lambda(list(target_vector_mu, 
                               context_vector_mu, 
                               target_vector_sigma, 
                               context_vector_sigma),
                          KLenergy)


output <- layer_dense(kl_energy, units = 1, activation = "relu")

# ================================
# model compile
# ================================
model <- keras_model(list(input_target, input_context), output)
model %>% compile(
   loss = "binary_crossentropy", 
  optimizer = "Adagrad")

summary(model)
```

Comment: Is `integer(1)` doing something special? Could you try just `axis=1`? --- Then, are the axes in R counted with first = 0 or first = 1? By your code, it seems like 1 is the first axis? If you try `axis=2` or `axis=integer(2)`, will it bring an error?

Comment: Without specifying integer, you get a type error (this is specific to using Keras via RStudio). It reads the 1 in "axis = 1" as a float but it expects and integer. As for using "axis = integer(2)" I still get a kl_energy layer with shape = (None, ).

Comment: Really? But isn't `integer(1)` creating a vector with zeros? https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.5.0/topics/integer

Comment: You're using just numbers everywhere else, why an error just in that place? If that is expecting an array, then you should create an array containing `1` inside.

Comment: You are absolutely right, silly mistake, it should be as.integer(1). I still get the same error though (i.e. the shape is still (None,) and the executing output gives the same error message.

Comment: I see, let me check with an array.

Comment: Same error unfortunately. Thanks for catching the integer error though.

Comment: Ok, now we have an answer, I guess, see below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't forget to use the `keepdims=TRUE` to return `(None,1)`.

And as discussed, you should use `as.integer(1)`, or `1L` in R notation.

Comment: That was it! Thanks for catching that Daniel, just needed an extra pair of eyes.

Comment: Note that you can write `as.integer(1)` as `1L`